# Conjugate Gradient implementation Python

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

I implemented Conjugate Gradient in python by looking into the Wikipedia reference - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method

The implementation should solve for

```
ax = b
```

my application inputs goes as below,

```
a = <400x400 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 1920 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
b = vector of shape (400, ) and dtype = float64
x = vector of random numbers of shape (400, )
```

Here is my implementation -

```
def ConjGrad(a, b, x):
       r = (b - np.dot(np.array(a), x));
       p = r;
       rsold = np.dot(r.T, r);

       for i in range(len(b)):
           a_p = np.dot(a, p);
           alpha = rsold / np.dot(p.T, a_p);
           x = x + (alpha * p);
           r = r - (alpha * a_p);
           rsnew = np.dot(r.T, r);
           if (np.sqrt(rsnew) < (10 ** -5)):
               break;
           p = r + ((rsnew / rsold) * p);
           rsold = rsnew;        
       return p
```

When i call the above CG function, i get an error within the function for the line -

```
r = (b - np.dot(np.array(a), x));
```

The error goes like this -

```
NotImplementedError: subtracting a sparse matrix from a nonzero scalar is 
not supported
```

At run time, below are the properties of variables within the CG function -

```
np.dot(np.array(a), x).shape
(400,)
b.shape
(400,)
```

I wonder why the subtraction is not happenning???

I tested the same function with the sample input arguments below and it worked fine.

```
a = np.array([[3, 2, -1], [2, -1, 1], [-1, 1, -1]]) # 3X3 symmetric matrix
b = (np.array([1, -2, 0])[np.newaxis]).T  # 3X1 matrix
x = (np.array([0, 1, 2])[np.newaxis]).T
```

Can someone please tell me why its not working for a sparse matrix?

Answer (score 2):

When multiplying a sparsa matrix by a array you should not use: **np.dot(np.array(a), x))** but  **a.dot(x)**. See the documentation below:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html

Follows a correct routine:

```
    def conjGrad(A,x,b,tol,N):

    r = b - A.dot(x)
    p = r.copy()
    for i in range(N):
        Ap = A.dot(p)
        alpha = np.dot(p,r)/np.dot(p,Ap)
        x = x + alpha*p
        r = b - A.dot(x)
        if np.sqrt(np.sum((r**2))) < tol:
            print('Itr:', i)
            break
        else:
            beta = -np.dot(r,Ap)/np.dot(p,Ap)
            p = r + beta*p
    return x
```